# Bootstrap SASS settings in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, bootstrap-sass, jekyll-bootstrap

I don't understand how I can set the precision required for bootstrap sass through jekyll.

Besides, I can't understand how jekyll automatically loads the files .scss who I placed in everywhere if I only set the _sass dir.

For example in my directory CSS I have a file named style.scss and it automatically generates the right css files in .site/css.

Below the piece of code about SASS settings:

```
 sass:
  sass_dir: _sass
  style: :nested
```

Thanks for your help,
Regards,
Silvio S.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to configure? Here is the [source code](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/configuration.rb) for Jekylls default configuration.

Comment: Hello, I have two questions: 1) I need to set the precision=8 for Bootstrap SASS 2) How jekyll automatically understand the source where from which it loads the scss files and generate the css files. I only setted the _sass directory but It is looking at my CSS directory as input.

Answer (score 0):

#### Sass precision

Sass precision cannot be set in Jekyll configuration. It can only be set in command line or in a ruby script (plugin)

#### What is the jekyll sass entry point ?

Jekyll will process any file with a [front matter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) with the appropriate converter. For sass and scss files it will use `jekyll-sass-converter`.

`css/main.scss` is processed, it is your **entry point**.

During this processing, the converter looks for `@import`ed files in the `sass_dir` path, which by default is `_sass`. It can be any path in your root folder.

Sass and scss files, once processed, are outputed with a `css` extension.

Comment: you can create as many entry point as you want. Just create sass or scss file with a front matter in it.